# Getting the jquery selector right

Tags: jquery

I have the following html :

```
<div class="mainmenu">
    <ul class="blue">
                <li class=""><a href="tst/" id="a1_up"><span class="all">tst1</span></a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="tst1/" id="a2_up"><span class="all">tst2</span></a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="tst3/" id="a3_up"><span class="all">tst3</span></a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="tst4/" id="a4_up"><span class="all">tst3</span></a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="tst5/" id="a5_up"><span class="all">tst4</span></a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="tst6/" id="a6_up"><span class="all">tst5</span></a></li>
              <li class=""><a href="tst7/" id="a7_up"><span class="all">tst6</span></a></li>
          </ul>
  </div>
```

I need to collect all span values this part `<span class="all">tst6</span>` I've tried this on jsbin:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".mainmenu ul li > span").each(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
    });
 });
```

But nothing happens. It's uploaded here :

http://jsbin.com/emulah

Live edit :

http://jsbin.com/emulah/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: which value do you want to collect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this: **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/mHfUs/5/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".mainmenu > ul > li > span").each(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});​
```

p.s. jsfiddle is acting funny else I had demo ready `:)`

`a` is between `li` and `span` as you can see in demo above: < this will work >

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('f');
    $("div.mainmenu ul li a span").each(function() {
        alert($(this).text());
    });
});​
```

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow Hey man seems like you have `a` tag between your `li` and `span` that makes the selector wrong, I am using jsbin for the first time hence taking time, `:)`

Comment: @GandalfStormCrow working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/mHfUs/5/ hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is totally wrong:

`">"` means `direct child`, and `span` is not a direct child of `li`, `a` is.

Either rewrite it as `.mainmenu ul li span`, or, better, use even shorter selector, like:

```
$('.mainmenu span.all')
```

or

```
$('.blue span')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your span elements doesn't have value (`val()`).

Try to get `text()` instead:

```
alert($(this).text());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [.map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) to get the result. (span don't have value, you should use `.text()` to get the innerHtml text)

```
var values = $(".mainmenu ul li > span").map(function() {
  return $(this).text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1- your `span` elements are not direct descendents of `li` elements, so the selector

```
(".mainmenu ul li > span")
```

won't match any element. write instead `$(".mainmenu li span")`

2- Instead of `val()` method use `text()` method

Answer (score 0):

Following is a solution to select right selector using jquery and apply proper properties on it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var result = '';
$(".mainmenu ul li span.all").each(function() {
    result += '<div><a href="#">' + $(this).text() + '</a></div>';
});
$('#result').html(result);
$("#result").addClass("output")
```

});

I have created a bin with the solution on http://codebins.com/codes/home/4ldqpcb